I am getting crm id not found error when I hit the swagger url in spring boot 3.3.2 and java 21 application
I have migrated my service from java 8 to 21 and spring boot 2.0.4 release to 3.3.2, so at the same time migrated swagger to springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui but after migrating all this while hitting swagger url I am getting error that crm id not found. Please refer my below code and help me here.
Thanks in advance.
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Value("${mx.version}")
    private String applicationVersion;

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info()
                        .title("Azure Storage Service")
                        .description("REST API for Azure Blob Storage.")
                        .version(applicationVersion)
                        .termsOfService("Terms of service")
                        .contact(new Contact()
                                .name("Base Platform Team")
                                .url("swagger-ui.html")
                                .email("3BasePlatformTeam@matrixcare.com"))
                        .license(new License().name("License").url("")));
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
@Configuration
@Order(2)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SwaggerApiSecurityConfig {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SwaggerApiSecurityConfig.class);

    public static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            // -- Swagger UI v3 (OpenAPI)
            "/v3/api-docs/**",
            "/swagger-ui/**",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            // other common paths for Swagger UI
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/webjars/**",
            // other public endpoints
            "/api/probe/**",
            "/favicon.ico",
    };

    @Value("${api.swagger.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${api.auth.basic.realm}")
    private String basicAuthRealm;
    private final ContainerSecretsLogic csl;


    @Autowired
    public SwaggerApiSecurityConfig(ContainerSecretsLogic csl, Environment env) {
        this.csl = csl;
        //this.username = env.getProperty(username,"swagger");
       // this.basicAuthRealm = env.getProperty(basicAuthRealm,"azure-storage-service");
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain swaggerApiSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        logger.debug("Configuring Swagger API security filter chain");

        http
                .securityMatcher("/swagger-ui/**")
                // Disable CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) protection
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)

                // Configure security for Swagger API endpoints
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                        // Whitelist paths that do not require authentication
                        .requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                        // Require authentication for any other request
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .authenticationManager(authManagerSwagger(http))
                // Configure HTTP Basic authentication
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                // Configure session management
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) // Stateless session management
                );

        return http.getOrBuild();
    }

    @Bean("swaggerApiAuthenticationManager")
    public AuthenticationManager authManagerSwagger(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser(username)
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode(csl.getSecretValue("mx1_platform_swagger_password", "swagger")))
                .roles("ADMIN");
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }

}

@Component
public class MultiClientValidationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultiClientValidationFilter.class);

    private final Map<String, AccessTokenVerifier> accessTokenVerifierMap = new HashMap<>();
    private String oktaBaseUrl;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
       /* String requestUri = request.getRequestURI();
        if (requestUri.startsWith("/swagger-ui") || requestUri.startsWith("/v3/api-docs")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }*/
        String requestCrmId = request.getParameter("crmid");
        Jwt jwt;

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(requestCrmId)) {
            String jwtString = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            jwtString = jwtString.replace("Bearer ", "");
            JSONObject tokenJason = extractJasonFromToken(jwtString);
            String issuer = tokenJason.getString("iss");
            String profileCrmId = null;
            String audience = tokenJason.getString("aud");
            if (tokenJason.has("crmid")) {
                profileCrmId = tokenJason.getString("crmid");
            }

            try {
                // Check if passed in CRM ID matches what we configured in Okta.  This prevents customers from accessing the wrong data store.
                if (profileCrmId != null) {
                    // First check request matches Okta App profile. New single auth server pattern
                    if (!requestCrmId.equalsIgnoreCase(profileCrmId)) {
                        throw new JwtVerificationException("Incorrect CRM ID");
                    }
                } else {
                    // Second check request matches Okta Auth audience. Legacy fallback where we used to create an auth server for each customer.
                    if (!requestCrmId.equalsIgnoreCase(audience)) {
                        throw new JwtVerificationException("Incorrect CRM ID");
                    }
                }

                // make sure that the auth server is correct.
                if (!issuer.startsWith(oktaBaseUrl)) {
                    throw new JwtVerificationException("Incorrect Auth server");
                }

                // Cache auth server.
                // audience is CRM ID in most cases but leaving the naming as audience so that we may have some flexibility in future in cases audience is used as facility ID or client ID
                // TODO should this only be cached after validation?
                AccessTokenVerifier jwtVerifier = null;
                if (accessTokenVerifierMap.containsKey(issuer + "_" + audience)) {
                    jwtVerifier = accessTokenVerifierMap.get(issuer + "_" + audience);
                } else {
                    jwtVerifier = JwtVerifiers.accessTokenVerifierBuilder()
                            .setIssuer(issuer)
                            .setAudience(audience)      // defaults to 'api://default'
                            .build();
                    accessTokenVerifierMap.put(issuer + "_" + audience, jwtVerifier);
                }

                // Validate JWT.
                jwt = jwtVerifier.decode(jwtString);    // this is where it is taking time
                if (jwt == null) {
                    throw new JwtVerificationException("Incorrect Token Signature");
                }

                logger.debug("Token validation successful");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error in Token validation", e);
                ErrorResult errorResult = new ErrorResult();
                errorResult.setCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
                errorResult.setMessage("Invalid access token");
                ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
                String json = ow.writeValueAsString(errorResult);
                response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
                response.getWriter().write(json);
                response.getWriter().close();
                return;
            }

        } else {
            // IF CRM ID is not given return error response. Note that this is applicable to all api calls.
            // Another option can be remove this else block and remove checking null condition on jwt down below and only perform validation is CRM is present.
            // Other calls will be allowed to pass through as they will not be performing container operations.
            // That options will be less rigid when it comes to security and provide the microservice flexibility to accept calls without CRM ID.
            logger.error("CRM ID not given");
            ErrorResult errorResult = new ErrorResult();
            errorResult.setCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
            errorResult.setMessage("CRM ID is required");
            ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
            String json = ow.writeValueAsString(errorResult);
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
            response.getWriter().write(json);
            response.getWriter().close();
            return;
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }


    private JSONObject extractJasonFromToken(String token) {
        String[] parts = token.split("\\.");
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(parts[1]);
        String decodedToken = new String(decodedBytes);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(decodedToken);
        return jsonObject;
    }


}

@Configuration
@Order(3)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultiClientSecurityConfig {

    @Value("${okta.client.orgUrl}")
    private String oktaBaseUrl;

    @Value("${okta.oauth2.audience}")
    private String mcAudience;

    private final MultiClientValidationFilter multiClientValidationFilter;

    @Autowired
    public MultiClientSecurityConfig(MultiClientValidationFilter multiClientValidationFilter) {
        this.multiClientValidationFilter = multiClientValidationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.securityMatcher("/api/**")
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .addFilterBefore(multiClientValidationFilter, CorsFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/**").permitAll());
        return http.getOrBuild();
    }
}

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>

